# Document compiling in one instance, but not the other (Beamer)

Tags: r-markdown, beamer

So, I'm not sure whether this has happened to anyone else, but I'm using Rmarkdown to create a beamer presentation. For whatever reason, there are some .Rmd files that are compiling, while others constantly go into "extended mode".

For instance, if I create a brand new .Rmd file, it will compile, but if I copy the contents of the document into another file (same exact thing), it goes into extended mode looking for pgf. Any understanding of why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that the problem was being caused by the auxiliary and intermediate files that are created once you try to compile the document. If you delete them, this should be resolved.